# twitter api not loading tweet on server while works fine on local

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have created one twitter app through [twitter api](https://apps.twitter.com/), but thing is that it works fine locally but when I took it to the server it doesn't work. [Check this page](http://yourwebseo.com/appmagic/appmagic/appmagic-black.html), I can't conclude the reason. Although I changed the url in api settings as well.

I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/pixel-industry/TweetScroll---jQuery-plugin)

I also doubt if it's curl base issue.

Comment: @Stefan I added it's url in api setting, if you are asking any thing other except it then tell me.

Comment: Some more code would be nice, what is your app doing? Fetching tweets from a hashtag?

Comment: @Gustaf I have used a plugin have added it's link into question.

Comment: Make sure you've set the right permissions on the requested files. In the "twitter" directory for example.

Comment: @Gustaf what permission you suggest ?

Comment: @Gustaf done no effect, I saw in browser console I think am not getting any data from server as well because it say "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81236/discussion-between-gustaf-and-nirmal).